# How to divide a column of floats by a column of datetime.time values in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

Say I have a dataframe that tracks TimeWorked which is type datetime.time in Hours/Min/Sec and TimeOff in seconds of type float per person:

```
 Name    TimeWorked    TimeOff
  Bob      00:55:44       20.4
 Jane      01:21:10        5.0
 Mike      00:10:14
```

TimeOff can be blank. How can I divide these two columns TimeOff/TimeWorked to end up with a new column called '%Off' which is a float that tracks the ratio between Off/Worked? If there is no time off, the '%Off' column should also be blank resulting in:

```
 Name    TimeWorked    TimeOff   %Off
  Bob      00:55:44       20.4   whatever (20.4 seconds/00:55:44) is as a float
 Jane      01:21:10        5.0   whatever (5.0 seconds/01:21:10) is as a float
 Mike      00:10:14
```

> df['%Off'] = df['TimeOff'] / df['TimeWorked']

currently returns *unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'datetime.time'*

Not too sure how I can provide a fully runnable example, since I can't force the example's type to be 'datetime.time'. The data I am receiving already comes that way. Here's what I'm trying to do to provide an example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['00:55:44', 20.4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns ['TimeWorked', 'TimeOff'])
new_dtypes = {'TimeWorked': 'datetime.time', 'TimeOff': 'float'}
df = df.astype(new_dtypes)
```

Running that gives 'datetime.time' not understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `timedelta`:

```
df['Off_pct'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['TimeOff'], unit='s')/
                 pd.to_timedelta(df['TimeWorked'].astype(str))
                )
```

Output:

```
   Name TimeWorked  TimeOff   Off_pct
0   Bob   00:55:44     20.4  0.006100
1  Jane   01:21:10      5.0  0.001027
2  Mike   00:10:14      NaN       NaN
```

Comment: thanks! you have once again saved me from a life of pain